# Cannot move members in Umbraco TypeError: contentResource.move is not a function

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, umbraco, document-types

In Umbraco 7.5.9 backoffice I have created another Member type called "Directory Member".  When I try to move a member from the "Member" type to the "Directory Member" type, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: contentResource.move is not a function
    at key (http://localhost/umbraco/js/umbraco.controllers.js?cdv=212109419:13928:43)
    at serial (http://localhost/umbraco/js/umbraco.controllers.js?cdv=212109419:13808:14)
    at applySelected (http://localhost/umbraco/js/umbraco.controllers.js?cdv=212109419:13829:14)
    at performMove (http://localhost/umbraco/js/umbraco.controllers.js?cdv=212109419:13926:8)
    at Object.$scope.moveDialog.submit (http://localhost/umbraco/js/umbraco.controllers.js?cdv=212109419:13905:17)
    at a.scope.submitForm (http://localhost/umbraco/js/umbraco.directives.js?cdv=212109419:5183:37)
    at http://localhost/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js?cdv=212109419:74:98
    at Object.d.(anonymous function) [as action] (http://localhost/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js?cdv=212109419:44:33)
    at http://localhost/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js?cdv=212109419:74:98
    at http://localhost/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular-mobile.js?cdv=212109419:270:9
```

I have not added any extra properties to the "Directory Member", it is basically a copy of the "Member" type.  I have tried reinstalling Umbraco, starting from scratch, and I still get this error.  I have checked the `UmbracoTraceLog` and nothing shows up relative to this backoffice error.  I am at a loss on how to debug this or figure out what the real issue is.  I have not found any issue reports in regards to this. I am also using Umbraco ModelBuilder with a value of "AppData".  After creating a new member type, I try to save and generate the models, and I get an error in the backoffice that states `Models generation has failed, see exception in U log`.  There is nothing in the Umbraco log. However the model is generated in `App_Data/Models/DirectoryMember.generated.cs`.  I have also tried using the Umbraco Logging DevTool extension in Chrome, and nothing shows up there either.

I notice that some properties are not able to be edited, such as the `IsLockedOut` property, which just says "No", and the `Password Question` and `Password Answer`, which I am assuming can only be answered by the member when you create a member front-end template.

So what am I missing?